# Counterexamples Invertibility

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, inverse

If A is an invertible matrix,

is A^t always invertible? If t is a fractional exponent, would it guarantee invertibility?

Comment: @Suzet can you clarify the introduction of B matrix? 

I was wondering based on A^t alone without introducing another matrix B. So for every t is A^t an invertible matrix given that A is already invertible

Comment: My bad IvyGatekeeper, I erased my comment after I noticed I misread your question ($A^t$ made me think about the transposed matrix of $A$ actually). Please, do not mind what I wrote.

Comment: As Suzet says, $A^t$ for matrices almost always means the transpose, not a power.

Answer (score 1):

Let $t=p/q$.

Let $B = A^t$, i.e. $B^q = A^p$. Then, $B^q (A^{-1})^p = A^p A^{-p} = I_n$, so $B(B^{q-1}A^{-p}) = I_n$, so $B$ is invertible, and $B^{q-1}A^{-p}$ is its inverse.

---

Caveat: in general, $A^{p/q}$ is not defined; if it is, it is not uniquely defined.

Comment: I guess to clarify my question, will A^t, for any t, be invertible given that A is an invertible matrix. 

Thank You

Comment: Did I not just prove that?